# How do I power fluorescent lights hanging from a drop ceiling?

Tags: light-fixture, nec

Our basement has a high ceiling, and somebody fancied it up with a drop ceiling.

The lighting is the common 4' 2-lamp fluorescent shop lights that are cord-and-plug connected, and hung from the drop ceiling stringers.  The cords go up into a corner of a drop ceiling panel and disappear... above the drop ceiling they plug into receptacles along the joists.  I believe cords above drop ceilings are not allowed.

What's the most expedient way to fix that?  How do I *properly* connect cord-and-plug connected lights in a drop ceiling?

If the voltage of the fixtures was much lower (say 24V) would that make the wiring scheme OK?

Comment: Do they have to be cord-and-plug? You could wire them up with type AC, MC, or even NM if it's a dwelling.

Comment: I read a few discussions that said because of how 400.12 is worded, 400.10(3) could allow the cords to be above a drop ceiling. I guess that's up to interpretation, and would depend on the AHJ. I don't personally agree with that, and would wire them up with proper cable if they were in my house.

Comment: @tester101 I'm hoping to avoid the job altogether, but I need to add more lighting and I don't want to replicate the old technique if it's not legal or smart.

Comment: I'd just use an AC or MC whip, and wire it into a junction box instead of a receptacle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at NEC Article 410.62 (1) conditions (1) & (2) Cord Connected Lampholders and Luminaires. It basically says you can't connect up the fluorescents the way you have them. I suggest the best way is to eliminate the receptacles you can use the boxes for junctions since they are accessible. Then use standard wiring practices and connect into the top of the fixture and junction inside the fluorescent.